# C# object validate against xsd file

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xsd

The question is can I validate c# object against xsd without serializing this object to the xml? If yes, please give me some quick sample.

Just to give You some introduction. I got reference to the external WCF service and I got some xsd file. I got some proxy objects requests/response for this service. In the service consumer side (just class library) I would like to validate response (c# object) against provided xsd. Can I do that without serializing response to the xml?

```
    public Response Consume(Request message)
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceClient serviceClient = new ServiceClient();
            var response = serviceClient.Execute(message);

            // Here I would like to validate response without serializing against xsd 

            return response;
        }
        catch (FaultException<ValidationFault> validationException)
        {
            throw validationException;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What did you try? Could you post your code? What did not work?

Comment: @nilsK I pasted code.

Comment: I didn't understand, why not to get the xml of your response object and validate against a xsd, any particular reason? Xsd are schemas to validate xml data, not objects.